# import multiple .csv files into R and ignore files with only header

Tags: r, csv

I have a question of which I cannot find the answer online and on SO. I was wondering if it's possible to import multiple .csv files from multiple directories all at once, but ignore files that only have headers (first line) and no data?

Something like this works, but only if all files have data:

```
all_csv = dir(dir, recursive=T, full.names=T, pattern="\\.csv$")

myfiles = lapply(all_csv,read.csv,sep=sep,dec=dec,stringsAsFactor=F,header=F,skip=1)

  for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){

    colnames(myfiles[[i]])[1:2] <- c("A","B")
        }

  combi <- do.call("rbind",myfiles)
```

Update: With .csv files of 0 data rows (only headers) included in the target directory, an error is returned at the 2nd command line:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

thank you.

Comment: this doesn't work as the error returned occurs before the loop, see updated OP.

Comment: You could use `readLines` and reject any where `length` is one

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unfamiliar with this function. How would I incorporate this in my coding?

Comment: I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be by using `header = FALSE` and `skip = 1`. If you drop these arguments, `read.csv` will return a zero row `data.frame` which you can then rename and `rbind` (if you use `plyr::ldply` you can avoid the `do.call` step.

Comment: I think so too. your suggestion works :) thansk